# How to set a column value :position to the :id of the item when creating new item with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a List controller/model/whatever-you-would-call-it and when I create a new one with a form, I want to set the :position column to its :id. I don't know how I would do this.

BTW position is of type Integer.

My Ideas:

- In the controller: lists_controller.rb, in the new method, or maybe the create method, add some code.
- Somewhere in the form when setting the other attributes, sneak that position puppy in there.
  *(I only want to set position to id when creating new list, not updating though)*
- In the model itself set it. 
  *(I do not want to set the :position to the :id when I am updating/editing, (only when creating new), the item so I am pretty sure this is not going to work)*

Here is some code to potentially help:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @list) do |form| %>
  <div class='addField'>
    <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description" %>
    <%= form.check_box :private,class: 'check_box' %>
  </div>
  <div class='addLabel'>
    <div>
      <%= form.label :name %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= form.label :description %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= form.label :private %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='submitNew'>
    <%= form.submit 'Done', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**lists_controller.rb**

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)

    if @list.save
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :description, :private)
  end
end
```

This is just a snippet of the controller.

If you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is position need to be provided by end user on UI? or do you want the position to be accepted inside form while creating the model? 

If not then you can assign id to position in after_create callback of model.

Comment: @NarenSisodiya How would I assign id to position in after_create?

Comment: got late in reply... AytanLeibowitz's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your List model to something like this:

list.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_position
  .... existing model code ...

  private
  def set_position
    self.update_attribute(:position, self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't like it when I put `after_create :set_position` in ListsController

Comment: **undefined method `after_create' for ListsController:Class Did you mean? after_action**

Comment: Oh sorry, I used a model callback. I'll update my example.

Comment: You could try self.id.to_i to convert to an integer